Stripe line_items with additional fields
It's any solutions to add additional fields to each line_items in Stripe Checkout, even if the price ID will be the same?
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('...')

$stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
  'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'price' => 'price_...',
      'quantity' => 1,
      'additional_field' => 'additional_value',
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',
]);


Can you reword your question?  What is it you are trying to do here?

@RyanM One product in many variants, dynamic variants

Sorry this is still very unclear.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Please update your original question with these details.
